# Flow to add user to old school SP People and Groups using REST API?

Tags: flow

Has anyone had any luck adding user to an old school People and Groups with Flow?

I'm assuming all the connectors for Azure and O365 focus on Office 365 groups, not permission groups. Google is clogged with results for Office 365 groups, so not having any luck there.

Am thinking HTTP request and SharePoint REST API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#bk_UserCol...

POST request example: Add a user to a group

url: "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web
    /sitegroups(7)/users
    ?@target=''",

method: "POST",

body: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName':'i:0#.w|domain\user' }",

headers: {
    "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

less painful than i thought it would be:

[image]